# Is it possible for a default log handler in glib to be passed multiple log levels?

Tags: logging, glib

The glib GLogLevelFlags enum is defined as:

```
typedef enum
{
  /* log flags */
  G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION          = 1 << 0,
  G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL              = 1 << 1,

  /* GLib log levels */
  G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR             = 1 << 2,       /* always fatal */
  G_LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL          = 1 << 3,
  G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING           = 1 << 4,
  G_LOG_LEVEL_MESSAGE           = 1 << 5,
  G_LOG_LEVEL_INFO              = 1 << 6,
  G_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG             = 1 << 7,

  G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK              = ~(G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL)
} GLogLevelFlags;
```

Is it possible for the [default handler](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Message-Logging.html#g-log-default-handler) to receive, for example, (G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR | G_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG) as its log level? Is this well-defined according to glib's API guarentees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it is.
Seeing as `G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK` is defined as a bitwise mask with all bits but 0 and 1 set, and

```
  g_log_set_handler ("GLib", G_LOG_LEVEL_MASK | G_LOG_FLAG_FATAL
                 | G_LOG_FLAG_RECURSION, my_log_handler, NULL);
```

is used as an example for adding a log handler for all messages from GLib, combining log levels is fine.

Also, consider the following quote for `g_log_set_handler`:

> Sets the log handler for a domain and a set of log levels

Finally, see [this tutorial](http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/gtk-gnome-intro.html), which, among other things, states:

> The GLogLevelFlags parameter is an enum of bit flags that define the character and specific channel of a logging message. The three you'll most likely use with logging handlers are `G_LOG_LEVEL_MESSAGE`, `G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING`, and `G_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR`. Since they are bit flags, you can use a binary OR operator to combine more than one channel into a single handler.

Comment: Yes, those are talking about setting up handlers, but it wouldn't seem to make sense for a specific message to belong to multiple channels, I wouldn't think?

Comment: Sure. The message won't belong to multiple channels. The handler will accept messages that belong to one of the channels that it was set to accept. i.e: if(message.channel & handler.accepted_channels) { // handle }